# binding dropdown list using json in post back dropdown data lose

Tags: asp.net

```
function fill_CountryPod(Id) {
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data3: "{}",
                    url: '../Handler.ashx?act=data7&val=' + Id,
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data3) {
                        var TotalItem = data3.length;
                        $("#<%= DDLPlaceOfDelivery.ClientID  %>").empty();
                        if (TotalItem > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < TotalItem; i++) {
                                $('#<%=DDLPlaceOfDelivery.ClientID %>').append('<option value="' + data3[i].Value + '">' + data3[i].Text + '</option>');
                            }
```

It's my code to bind dropdownlist after post back dropdown became blank

```
$('#<%=PlaceOfDeliveryText.ClientID %>').val($('<%=DDLPlaceOfDelivery.ClientID %> option:selected').text());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on this? when are you binding this dropdown list?

Comment: yes praveen am binding drop down using handler above code

Comment: Hmm I think you should bind that dropdown on server if that are WebForms, or if u use ASP.MVC you can create hidden form field for that value and bind to dropdown's change event that would assign this hidden field

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek, I recommend a small change on this below line of yours.

```
var TotalItem = data3.length;
```

I recommend you to change the **data3.length** to **Object.keys(data3).length**. Such that it looks as below:

```
var TotalItem = Object.keys(data3).length;
```

This is because, the length of your Json string cant be fetched by simple data3.length, kindly try the change that i specified.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: my code also run but problem is on page post back. after post back drop down become blank.. data3.length also fetch length its not a problem.....

Comment: Dear praveen when we run drop down populated after page post back it will blank. thats my problem